A number theory question: Let $a, b > 0$. Prove that the sequence $S(\lfloor {an+b}\rfloor)$ contains a constant sub-sequence.
Here's the question:
Let $a, b > 0$. Prove that the sequence $S(\lfloor{an+b}\rfloor)$ contains a constant sub-sequence.
$S(n)$ is the function that gives the sum of digits of a number $n$.
Note- $n$ belongs to the set of natural numbers.
What I could decipher from this question is that there must exist a number (which is the sum of digits of some number) that repeats several times in this sequence. Now the problem is to find, what is that number. From there, it can be proved that such a sub-sequence does exist.
My teacher and I have been stuck on this problem for 2 days and cannot figure out a proper approach to this question. Any help will be appreciated. Many thanks for considering my request

Is $S(n)$ recursive? I mean does $S(29)$ equals $11$ or $2$?

@EnEm S(29) = 11, its not recursive

Lets label the sequence as $$\alpha_i = S(\lfloor ai + b\rfloor) \quad \forall i\in\mathbb{N}_0$$
Then I create another sequence $$\beta_i = \lim_{k\rightarrow\inf}\left(\min_{j=i}^{j=k}\alpha_j\right) \quad \forall i\in\mathbb{N}_0$$
I prove this sequence is bounded by $$ M = 1 + 9 \cdot\left( \left\lfloor \log_{10} a \right\rfloor + 1 \right)$$
which I will use to show that $\alpha_i$ has a constant subsequence.
Proof of bound $M$ for $\beta_i$
For all $i\in\mathbb{N}_0$,
$$\begin{split}
\beta_i &= \lim_{k\rightarrow\inf}\left(\min_{j=i}^{j=k}\alpha_j\right) \\
&\leq \alpha_j \qquad \text{for some specific } j\geq i
\end{split}$$
Lets take the $j$ where $aj + b$ crosses a $10$-power for the first time, i.e.,
$$\begin{split}
aj+b &\geq 10^{(1 + \lfloor\log_{10} (ai + b)\rfloor)}\\
j &\geq \frac{10^{(1 + \lfloor\log_{10} (ai + b)\rfloor)} - b}{a}\\
j &= \left\lceil \frac{10^{(1 + \lfloor\log_{10} (ai + b)\rfloor)} - b}{a} \right\rceil\\
\end{split}$$
As $0\leq \lceil x \rceil - x < 1$, we can easily show
$$\begin{split}
0 &\leq (aj + b) - 10^{(1 + \lfloor\log_{10} (ai + b)\rfloor)} &< a \\
10^t &\leq \lfloor aj+b \rfloor &< 10^t +a \\
1 &\leq S(\lfloor aj+b \rfloor) &\leq 1 + 9\cdot(\text{number of digits in }a)
\end{split}$$
$$\beta_i \leq \alpha_j \leq M$$
Proof that a constant subsequence exists
I quickly show $\beta_i$ is a non-decreasing integer sequence, for all $i\in \mathbb{N}_0$ :
$$\begin{split}
\beta_i &= \lim_{k\rightarrow\inf} \left( \min_{j=i}^{j=k} \alpha_j \right)\\
\beta_i &= \lim_{k\rightarrow\inf} \left( \min\left( \alpha_i, \min_{j=i+1}^{j=k} \alpha_j \right) \right) \\
\beta_i &= \min\left( \alpha_i, \lim_{k\rightarrow\inf} \left( \min_{j=i+1}^{j=k} \alpha_j \right) \right) \\
\beta_i &= \min(\alpha_i, \beta_{i+1})\\
\beta_i &\leq \beta_{i+1}
\end{split}$$
Now as the sequence $\beta_i$ is a bounded and non-decreasing integer sequence, it will increase $\beta_{i+1}>\beta_i$ only at finitely many $i$'s. Lets label the last $i$ at which it will increase to be $i_0$.
For all $i > i_0$, $\beta_i$ will be constant, so label any $i > i_0$ where $\alpha_i = \beta_{i_0 + 1}$ to be at $i_1$. Label the next $i> i_1$ where $\alpha_i = \beta_{i_0 + 1}$ to be at $i_2$, and so on.
Then the subsequence $[\alpha_{i_1}, \alpha_{i_2}, \alpha_{i_3}, \dots]$ is a constant subsequence.
